# How to add all values from collections.frequency for getting duplicate words using java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, text

```
for(String temp : uniqueSet) {
    if((Collections.frequency(list, temp)) >= 2) {
        System.out.println(temp + "=" + (Collections.frequency(list, temp) -1));
    }
}
```

I just want to add my repeated words count.But i cant find it.

In my code snippet,I want to get the frequently occurred words from an text file.

The problem is i can get the values of repeated words like ram=4 sam = 4 man =2,From the text file.
Now,

I want to add 4+4+2 and get total repeated word count as 10.

Any suggestions Welcomed.

I am a beginner to java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
public class testsrepeatedwords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".txt");
        }
    };

    File folder = new File("E:\\testfolder\\");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(filter);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        File file1 = listOfFiles[i];
        try {
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file1);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader ins = null;

        try {
            ins = new BufferedReader ( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file1)));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {       e.printStackTrace();  }

        String message = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(ins);
        String[] stringarray = message.split(" "); 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringarray));  
        list.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
        Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list); 
        for (String temp : uniqueSet) { 
                if ( (Collections.frequency(list, temp)  ) >= 2 ){

                    System.out.println(temp+"="+(Collections.frequency(list, temp)  -1)  );             //after subtraction 

                int oc = (Collections.frequency(list, temp)  -1) ;
            //  System.out.println(oc);     
           // System.out.print(oc+" ");


        } 
        }
        }}}
```

This is my full code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a map to store the current count? Something like this:

```
public static void getRepeatCount(String[] c) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
    for(String currStr : c) {
        if(wordCount.containsKey(currStr)) {
            wordCount.put(currStr, wordCount.get(currStr) + 1);
        } else {
            wordCount.put(currStr,1);
        }
    }
    int repeatedWords = 0;
    for (String currKey : wordCount.keySet()) {
        int currRepeatCount = wordCount.get(currKey);
        repeatedWords += currRepeatCount;
        System.out.println(currKey+" => "+currRepeatCount);
    }
    System.out.println("Total reapeated words: "+repeatedWords);
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                    
    String[] ar = {"abc","abc","aa","aa","b"};
    getRepeatCount(ar); 
}
```

Output:

```
aa  => 2
b   => 1
abc => 2
Total reapeated words: 5
```

Comment: Yes:) I Can use map and tried !.But From your String,The total count is= 2+1+2=5.Like this exactly I want to get the output.

Answer (score 1):

is 'uniqueSet' is really a Set? In set elements appeared only once. You should check your uniqueSet implementation first. If this is really a Set then Collections.frequency(list, temp)) >= 2 is always false.

Comment: When you put duplications to set thereis only one record. With this you remove all duplication Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list); Iterate thru list instead of uniqueSet.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8's streaming API provides a pretty elegant way of doing this. You could stream the list of words, collect it to a frequency map and then stream that map's values and reduce them to a sum:

```
int countThreshold = 2;
long sum =
    words.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                         Collectors.counting()))
          .values()
          .stream()
          .filter(x -> x >= countThreshold)
          .reduce(0L, Long::sum);
```